# java spring - getting null value when validating using a custom validator/annotations and a confirmation page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, customvalidator

We're using spring annotations and I'm having trouble figuring out why my one of my command object values is null. 
I'm attempting to validate a credit card field.

1.) When I fill out the 1st page and click enter, the validator verifies the form is correct and I am sent to the confirmation page.

2.) However, once on the confirmation page I click enter, when the validator runs this time my field "tempCard" is now null but other fields on the form contain their correct values. This is a payment page and the null value only happens when I manually type in a credit card into the "tempCard" field.

3.) If I choose a customer who has a previous credit card payment and I load their card information into "tempCard" then "tempCard" stays populated throughout the validation of the paymentStart jsp and the paymentConfirm jsp and processes normally.

Anyone have any ideas on how my tempCard field is getting set to null after the confirmation page?

This is code from my controller...

```
    @Controller  
    @RequestMapping(value = "/payment.*")  
    public final class PaymentController {  

    @Autowired  
    private CompoundPaymentValidator paymentValidator;  

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "step=confirm")  
    public String doConfirm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("command") final     CompoundPayment       form, final BindingResult result, final Model model,  
        final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final  HttpSession session) throws Exception {  
    synchronized (WebUtils.getSessionMutex(session)) {  
        if (result.hasErrors()) {  
            return doGet(form, result, model, request);  
        }  
    }  

    return "/paymentConfirm";  
}  

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "step=pay")  
public String doPost(@Valid @ModelAttribute("command") final CompoundPayment form, final BindingResult result, final Model model,  
        final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final     HttpSession session) throws Exception {  
    synchronized (WebUtils.getSessionMutex(session)) {  
        if (result.hasErrors()) {  
            return doGet(form, result, model, request);  
        }  


@InitBinder(value = "command")  
protected void initBinder(final ServletRequestDataBinder binder) {  
    binder.setValidator(paymentValidator);  
    final NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();  
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);  
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);  
    binder.registerCustomEditor(BigDecimal.class, new CustomNumberEditor(BigDecimal.class, nf, true));  
}  

@ModelAttribute("command")  
protected CompoundPayment initCommand(final HttpServletRequest request, final Model model) {  
            \\ i shortened this method 
    final CompoundPayment form = new CompoundPayment();
    return form; 
     }
```

I didn't show you the doGet method in the controller above but it sends me to my 1st jsp "/paymentStart" where I complete the payment information. My CompoundPayment object used as the command object contains several other java pojo objects one of which is a creditCardPayment object. On the jsp's I basically have only shown you the hidden field step which is used in the controller and the tempCard field.

Some code from my 1st `jsp paymentStart`...

```
 <form:form id="theForm" action="payment.htm"  
    onsubmit="return submitForm();">  
         <input type="hidden" name="step" value="confirm" />  
         <form:input path="creditCardPayment.tempCard" type="text"
             id="creditCardNo"  size="20" maxlength="18" 
              cssErrorClass="errorField" pattern="[0-9]*" />
    </form>
```

This is part of my **CreditCardPayment.java**

```
    public class CreditCardPayment extends AbstractPayment {  

              private String creditCardNo;  
              private int expirationMonth;  
              private int expirationYear;  
              private String cardType;  
              private String tempCard;
```

This is code from my **paymentConfirm.jsp**...

```
    <form:form id="theForm" action="payment.htm" onsubmit="return submitForm();">  
            <input type="hidden" name="step" value="pay" />
```

Comment: How are you binding `commandName`, i cannot see tha ti your controller layer.

Comment: I'm not using commandName...

Comment: question is not clear, can you elaborate little more.

Comment: Order is `(doGet -> ? ) -> doPost -> paymentStart -> doConfirm -> paymentConfirm -> payment.htm` , right ? And at what step in the chain does tempCar become null ?

Comment: Order is doGet > paymentStart.jsp > doConfirm > paymentConfirm.jsp > doPost

Comment: doConfirm runs the validator and works but after the paymentConfirm.jsp the doPost runs the validator again and this is where tempCard is sometimes null.

Comment: tempCard becomes null in the doPost